# What is the purpose of the question marks before type declaration in PHP7 (?string or ?int)?

Tags: php, php-7, type-hinting

Could you please tell me how is this called? `?string` and `string`

Usage example:

```
public function (?string $parameter1, string $parameter2) {}
```

I wanted to learn something about them but I cannot find them in PHP documentation nor in google. What is difference between them?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

### What is a Nullable Type?

Introduced in PHP 7.1,

> Type declarations for parameters and return values can now be marked as nullable by prefixing the type name with a question mark. This signifies that as well as the specified type, NULL can be passed as an argument, or returned as a value, respectively.

#### In parameters

```
function test(?string $parameter1, string $parameter2) {
    var_dump($parameter1, $parameter2);
}

test("foo", "bar");
test(null, "foo");
test("foo", null); // Uncaught TypeError: Argument 2 passed to test() must be of the type string, null given,
```

##### With variadic arguments

In this example, you can pass `null` or `string` parameters :

```
function acceptOnlyStrings(string ...$parameters) { }
function acceptStringsAndNull(?string ...$parameters) { }

acceptOnlyStrings('foo', null, 'baz'); // Uncaught TypeError: Argument #2 must be of type string, null given
acceptStringsAndNull('foo', null, 'baz'); // OK
```

#### Return type

The return type of a function can also be a nullable type, and allows to return `null` or the specified type.

```
function error_func(): int {
    return null ; // Uncaught TypeError: Return value must be of the type integer
}

function valid_func(): ?int {
    return null ; // OK
}

function valid_int_func(): ?int {
    return 2 ; // OK
}
```

#### Property type (as of PHP 7.4)

The type of a property can be a nullable type.

```
class Foo
{
    private object $foo = null; // ERROR : cannot be null
    private ?object $bar = null; // OK : can be null (nullable type)
    private object $baz; // OK : uninitialized value
}
```

See also :

**Nullable union types (as of PHP 8.0)**

As of PHP 8, *"`?T` notation is considered a shorthand for the common case of `T|null`"*

```
class Foo
{
    private ?object $bar = null; // as of PHP 7.1+
    private object|null $baz = null; // as of PHP 8.0
}
```

### Error

In case of the running PHP version is lower than PHP 7.1, a syntax error is thrown:

> syntax error, unexpected '?', expecting variable (T_VARIABLE)

The `?` operator should be removed.

PHP 7.1+

```
function foo(?int $value) { }
```

PHP 7.0 or lower

```
/** 
 * @var int|null 
 */
function foo($value) { }
```

### References

As of [PHP 7.1: **Nullable type**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration71.new-features.php#migration71.new-features.nullable-types) :

As of [PHP 7.4](https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration74.new-features.php#migration74.new-features.core.typed-properties): Class properties type declarations.

As of [PHP 8.0](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.declarations.php#language.types.declarations.union.nullable): Nullable Union Type

Comment: Just a note - optional parameters don't need question mark: `function foo(int $val = null) { var_dump($val); }`. However, careful with return types: `function foo(int $val = null): int { return (int)$val; }` - call `foo();`

Answer (score 4):

The question mark before the `string` in your function parameter denotes a **[nullable type](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/nullable_types)**. In your above example, `$parameter1` **must** is allowed to have a `NULL` value, whereas `$parameter2` is not; it must contain a valid string.

> Parameters with a nullable type do not have a default value. If omitted the value does not default to null and will result in an error:
>
> function f(?callable $p) { }
> f(); // invalid; function f does not have a default

Answer (score 1):

That means that the argument is allowed to be passed as the specified type or NULL:

http://php.net/manual/en/migration71.new-features.php

Answer (score 1):

This is roughly equivalent to

```
 public function (string $parameter1 = null, string $parameter2) {}
```

Except that the argument is still required, and an error will be issued if the argument is omitted.

Specifically in this context, the second argument is required and using `=null` would make the first optional, which doesn't really work.  Sure it works but what I mean that it does not actually make it optional, which is the main purpose of default values.

So using

```
public function (?string $parameter1, string $parameter2) {}
```

Syntactically makes a bit more sense in this instance.