# php method argument type hinting with question mark (?type)

Tags: php

I just felt on pieces of php (symfony/laravel) code using question mark in method type hints :

```
public function functionName(?int $arg = 0)
```

In other occasions the **?type** was not the last one, but I did not find any of these with no default yet.

Problem is, I cannot find any information about this, and I checked :

- here : http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.new-features.php
- and here : http://php.net/manual/en/migration71.new-features.php
- and here : http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php

And same with 7.2, but since the code only requires 7.1, it seems rather normal.

I also googled, and searched here, but either this is not documented or the question marks topic is defeating search engines.

So I feel a little dumb now, and I would really appreciate if someone could enlighten me on the significance of this question mark in method signatures arguments.

Thanks

Comment: https://wiki.php.net/rfc/nullable_types

Comment: You're right lol. The worst thing is I knew about the meaning as return value. Thanks for the enlightenment

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the purpose of the question marks before type declaration in PHP7 (?string or ?int)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48450739/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-question-marks-before-type-declaration-in-php7-stri)

Answer (score 49):

It's a new feature in php7.1

http://php.net/manual/en/migration71.new-features.php

A question mark means that the type hinted parameter (or return value) is also allowed to be null.

So in your example $arg can be null or any integer.

Comment: See also [this detailed answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48450841/9193372)

Answer (score 16):

Just a note to add to the previous answers - it must be either `null` or have a value in the specified type i.e. - you cannot just omit it - have a look at an example:

```php
class TestClass {

    public function fetch(?array $extensions)
    {
        //...
    }        
}
```

Now if you call

```php
(new TestClass)->fetch();
```

this will throw

> ArgumentCountError : Too few arguments to function fetch() ...

To make it work without passing array of `$extensions` you'd have to call it with `null` as argument

```
(new TestClass)->fetch(null);
```

It works best in the situations, where you are passing argument initially set to `null` to another method for processing i.e.

```php
class TestClass {

    public function fetch(array $extensions = null)
    {
        //...

        $this->filter($extensions);
    }

    private function filter(?array $extensions)
    {
        //...
    }
}
```

Now you can call the `fetch` method without the argument

```php
(new TestClass)->fetch();
```

Comment: Exactly, and it makes perfect sens, without a default value, you only have the right to explicitly set the argument to null with the question mark, and with one, you can completely omit it.

Comment: What's the difference between having `private function filter(?array $extensions)` and `private function filter(array $extensions = null)`

Comment: @Quiquetas `(?array $p)` $p must be an array or null, anyway it must be provided on call. `(?array $p=null)` just the same, $p must be an array or null, but with default value to null, this parameter could be omitted on call this time. And about the `public function fetch(array $extensions = null)` snippet, well, ti's just a potential error because $extensions cannot be null. But would trigger only if fetch is called with no arguments, like this `$obj->fetch();`. The why is written above.

Answer (score 10):

Consider the following functions:

```
<?php

function testFnc1(string $param)
{
    var_dump($param);
}

function testFnc2(string $param = 'some string')
{
    var_dump($param);
}
    
function testFnc3(string $param = null)
{
    var_dump($param);
}

function testFnc4(?string $param)
{
    var_dump($param);
}

function testFnc5(?string $param = 'some string')
{
    var_dump($param);
}


function testFnc6(?string $param = null)
{
    var_dump($param);
}
```

Now we test the functions with different values.

| fnc | no argument | null | '' | 'other string' |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | FATAL ERROR Uncaught ArgumentCountError | FATAL ERROR Uncaught TypeError: Argument 1 passed to testFnc1() must be of the type string, null given | string(0) "" | string(12) "other string" |
| 2 | string(11) "some string" | FATAL ERROR Uncaught TypeError: Argument 1 passed to testFnc2() must be of the type string, null given | string(0) "" | string(12) "other string" |
| 3 | NULL | NULL | string(0) "" | string(12) "other string" |
| 4 | FATAL ERROR Uncaught ArgumentCountError | NULL | string(0) "" | string(12) "other string" |
| 5 | string(11) "some string" | NULL | string(0) "" | string(12) "other string" |
| 6 | NULL | NULL | string(0) "" | string(12) "other string" |

Notice the difference between `testFnc3(string $param = null)` and `testFnc4(?string $param)` when:

1. no argument is passed
2. the argument is `null`

You can call `testFnc3()` but not `testFnc4()` as it does not declare a *default value*.

You must call `testFnc4(null)`.

So `testFnc4(?string $param)` allows `$param` to be `null`, but such parameter MUST be provided.