# What do the question marks mean in a PHP function signature?

Tags: php

In php, what do the question marks mean in this function signature?

```
private static function getBooleanAnnotationSetting(string $className, ?string $methodName, string $settingName): ?bool {
}
```

Comment: I'm kinda wondering if I pulled a bad composer package.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/48450841/9193372

Comment: It's great that we all keep stackoverflow clean, but I'm going to leave this Q/A pair up because it's easy to find.  People who don't know what the question mark means - we aren't going to be searching for "nullable".  Sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question mark represents [a nullable type](http://php.net/manual/en/migration71.new-features.php#migration71.new-features.nullable-types):

> Type declarations for parameters and return values can now be marked as nullable by prefixing the type name with a question mark. This signifies that as well as the specified type, NULL can be passed as an argument, or returned as a value, respectively.

This allows you to provision `null` as an argument without receiving a `TypeError`.