# What does question mark (?) before type declaration means in php (?int)

Tags: php, php-7.2

I have seen this code in https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Component/Console/Output/Output.php line number 40 they are using ?int.

```
public function __construct(?int $verbosity = self::VERBOSITY_NORMAL, bool $decorated = false, OutputFormatterInterface $formatter = null)
    {
        $this->verbosity = null === $verbosity ? self::VERBOSITY_NORMAL : $verbosity;
        $this->formatter = $formatter ?: new OutputFormatter();
        $this->formatter->setDecorated($decorated);
    }
```

Comment: It means it should be an int but can also be null

Comment: Nullable type: http://php.net/manual/en/migration71.new-features.php

Comment: The issue that php 7.2 does not support this

Comment: @MaxChernopolsky Could you please provide a reference of your claim "_php 7.2 does not support Nullable types_"?

Comment: I was wrong. It does.

Comment: PHP_EOL (string)
The correct 'End Of Line' symbol for this platform. Available since PHP 5.0.2

Answer (score 104, accepted):

It's called `Nullable types`.

Which defines `?int` as either `int` or `null`.

> Type declarations for parameters and return values can now be marked as nullable by prefixing the type name with a question mark. This signifies that as well as the specified type, NULL can be passed as an argument, or returned as a value, respectively.

Example :

```
function nullOrInt(?int $arg){
    var_dump($arg);
}

nullOrInt(100);
nullOrInt(null);
```

function `nullOrInt` will accept both null and int.

Ref: http://php.net/manual/en/migration71.new-features.php

Comment: So... it's a weakly typed strong type? :D

Comment: Well, languages like C# or Java when asking for an object, allows to pass null, so you can get null pointer exceptions easily unless you verify every parameter on every function manually because they are passing a *pointer*. In PHP you have to ask explicitly that you want an object, or an object or null because PHP passes a *reference*.

In that sense, the parameters seem more strongly typed to me, compared with those languages (besides the fact that PHP is not a statically typed language).

Comment: what version php will be support?

Comment: @MrTo-Kane nullable type is introduced in PHP 7.1

Comment: See also [this **detailed answer** about **Nullable types**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48450841/9193372)