# PHP functions attached with ":" and "?" , what does it do?

Tags: php, function

I found out a php file inside which it had a function like below:

```
public function getCharset(): ?string
{
    return $this->charset;
}
```

I want to know what is **: ?string** doing here.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the purpose of the question marks before type declaration in PHP7 (?string or ?int)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48450739/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-question-marks-before-type-declaration-in-php7-stri)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is known as a [**nullable type**](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/nullable_types), and is **[introduced in PHP 7.1](http://php.net/manual/en/migration71.new-features.php)**:

> Type declarations for parameters and return values can now be marked as nullable by prefixing the type name with a question mark. This signifies that as well as the specified type, `NULL` can be passed as an argument, or returned as a value, respectively.

Essentially, the function can return **either** the specified type **or** `null`. If it would return a different type, an error is thrown:

```
function answer(): ?int  {
    return null; // ok
}

function answer(): ?int  {
    return 42; // ok
}

function answer(): ?int {
    return new stdclass(); // error
}
```

Comment: That's convenient.