# hosting Laravel 5.5 on shared hosting (T_VARIABLE) error

Tags: laravel, syntax-error, cpanel, shared-hosting, parse-error

First I must say that this question has been asked thousands of time.
I created my Laravel 5.5 project using:

```
composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel blog "5.5.*"
```

I **didn't** add anything to the project. The project runs locally without a problem.
The problem arrives when I want to host the project on a shared hosting website(I'm using **infinityfree.net**)

Minimum PHP version for Laravel 5.5: **PHP >= 7.0.0**

My shared hosting site php version: **PHP Version 7.0.19**

The only changes that I made are these:

1. I copied the contents of ***public*** folder to the root folder of my project.
2. Then I put the entire Laravel app in the **htdocs** folder of the shared hosting site.

so the structure looks like this :

```
--htdocs 
    app
    bootstrap
    ...
    index.php
    js
    css
    ...
    routes
    vendors
    ...
```

3. I changed these two lines in **index.php** (The app worked locally without a problem):

   require **DIR**.'/../vendor/autoload.php';

   -- I changed it to  -->

   require **DIR**.'/vendor/autoload.php';

   $app = require_once **DIR**.'/../bootstrap/app.php';

   -- I changed it to  -->

   $app = require_once **DIR**.'/bootstrap/app.php';

I still get this common error:

> laravel.ERROR: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '?', expecting variable (T_VARIABLE) {"exception":"[object] (Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError(code: 0): Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '?', expecting variable (T_VARIABLE) at /home/vol11_7/epizy.com/epiz_22148680/htdocs/vendor/symfony/http-kernel/Exception/HttpException.php:24)
>   [stacktrace]

[Link to my laravel.log file](https://github.com/ghasemikasra39/laravel5.5/blob/master/storage/logs/laravel.log)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the purpose of the question marks before type declaration in PHP7 (?string or ?int)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48450739/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-question-marks-before-type-declaration-in-php7-stri)

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use this to solve your problem.

```
require DIR.'../vendor/autoload.php';

$app = require_once DIR.'../bootstrap/app.php';
```

Comment: I don't understand your modification. I have to change these two lines. Otherwise, the app cannot find autoload.php and app.php

Answer (score 0):

Laravel 5 require higher php version, you need change the php version to 7.1 or 7.2 on your hosting

What you use current php version ?