# Null check on type hinting php

Tags: php, laravel, null

```
public function update(?User $user, Post $post)
{
   return $user->id === $post->user_id;
}
```

In the above function there is a '?' in front of User model type hinting.

What is the use case of this operator in function parameter?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48450739/what-do-the-question-marks-do-before-the-types-of-variables-in-the-parameters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This means that the argument is also allowed to be null: [Nullable Types](http://php.net/manual/en/migration71.new-features.php#migration71.new-features.nullable-types)