# PHP: is Nullable Argument Type available as Nullable Return Type?

Tags: php, php-7

## Is It Possible to use Nullable Argument Type as return type??

> From: https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.returning-values.php
>
> ```
> function get_item(): ?string {
>    if (isset($_GET['item'])) {
>        return $_GET['item'];
>    } else {
>        return null;
>    }
> }
> ```

After reading when i tested it with argument and run it. IT DID NOT CAUSE ANY `ParseError` but through it showed `ArgumentCountError` as probable.

```
function abc(?string $c) {
    return $c || FALSE;
}

var_dump(abc());
```

I know i can have optional argument like this (Which workds just fine):

```
function abc(string $c = null) {
    return $c || FALSE;
}

var_dump(abc());
```

### So, My question is,

- Why PHP is not throwing a Parse Error When i add `?` this in argument ??
- If, its some kind of a feature what's that ??

Comment: Why there should be `ParseError`? What incorrect or mistake syntax do you see?

Comment: because, i add `?` before the arguments type hint.

Comment: And what? `?string` is a correct type hint.

Comment: `?string` typehint means that function uses `string value` or `null` as argument. Same as for return type - function returns `string value` or `null`.

Comment: Yeah, i got it. thanks!!!

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/48450841/9193372