# PHP Nullable types and function parameters

Tags: php, function, parameters, nullable

I want to ask if both are the same and if not, where's the difference between them:

```
/**
 * @param int|null $id Any id.
 */
public function testSomething(int $id = null) {}
```

and

```
/**
 * @param int|null $id Any id.
 */
public function testSomething(?int $id) {}
```

Thank you for your answer!

Comment: the only difference I can see is that you _cannot_ invoke `testSomething(?int $id) {}` without arguments - will probably throw a fatal error, whereas you _can_ invoke the first case `testSomething(int $id = null) {}` without arguments.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the purpose of the question marks before type declaration in PHP7 (?string or ?int)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48450739/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-question-marks-before-type-declaration-in-php7-stri)

Comment: @FryingPan you can mark the answer bellow as correct

Answer (score 5):

It's different. The first function declaration :

```php
public function testSomething(int $id = null) {}
```

sets the default value to null, if you call the function without an argument.

The second definition :

```php
public function testSomething(?int $id) {}
```

will accept a null value as the first argument, but does not set it to a default value if the argument is missing. So you always need to have an argument if you call the function in the second way.