# what is the meaning of "?array" in PHP language?

Tags: php, arrays

I just was reading a snippet of code with this line:

```
private static ?array $labels = null;
```

all is clear for me, except the question mark before the `array` datatype.
Can you, please, explain me the presence of this little `?` thing here?

TIA

Comment: See also [question marks before type declaration in PHP7](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48450739/9193372)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means that the variable `$labels` is allowed to be `null` as well as an `array`.

Comment: Ah, ok, I think I got it.
It means I declared it an array, but exceptionally it can be **null** too.
Thank you, Daan.